# When is the html page header served to browser in asp.net page life cycle?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does this happen after any page life cycle event ? I noticed, that if some stylesheet links are added in page pre-render it is served to browser. I was just curious about the exact timing when this happens and how does this take place ?

Answer (score 1):

The header is just part of the client side HTML and doesn't have a specific place in the ASP.NET server side page life-cycle.

You can find more info on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So, if a link is added to the HTML head, will the browser make a second request for the link before rendering the full html ?

Comment: It will yes, but this is not part of the ASP.NET page lifecycle, this is part of the browser rendering the page.

Any external link (css, js etc) will incur an extra request, after the initial request for the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between browser rendering and ASP.Net life cycle. `prerender` `render` doesn't match with the rendering the output in browser. browser send the request to the server and then server process the ASP.net life cycle. then in render event it convert asp.net code to HTML code then it will send the response to the browser. browser will render the received html.

Comment: Do you mean the whole HTML code is served at once ?

Comment: yes. any css and js file reference load after  that

Comment: And the page is rendered in the browser once all the resources have been loaded ?

Comment: page render the html response and then it will apply the styles when they complete loading